# Mimic Dropbox App video streaming - HTTP live streaming directly trough Mp4

Tags: ios, video, amazon-web-services, mpmovieplayercontroller, dropbox-api

I have mp4 files on my dropbox account and when I play them on my iphone, they are correctly adapted to use Apple's HTTP Live Streaming.

I'm trying to do the same on my own app and can't get it to work correctly. I've tried linking from dropbox and from amazon aws.

I've seen on a few places that we must link to playlists files `m3u8`. But my files are `mp4` and it works correctly on dropbox own app.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.player.moviePlayer];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/modlr_backups/CANELEIRA+4+APOIOS+BI-ARTICULADA.mp4"];

    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
    self.player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [self.player.moviePlayer setContentURL:url];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player];
```

Comment: Dropbox transcodes the video for you when you play a video. If you want to mimic this, you'll need to do your own transcoding first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox had a blog post that explains exactly how they do it:
https://tech.dropbox.com/2014/02/video-processing-at-dropbox/

Comment: Thanks, that is a very good post. I know Dropbox doesn't offer this on their api, but my idea is to store the mp4 somewhere where I could have direct streaming without having to worry about encoding. Maybe Amazon?